# Service Starts and Stops when Hosting WCF in Window Service

Tags: wcf, windows-services

i have Hosted a WCF service in a Windows Services and its installed in the Windows
but when i try to start the service,the service starts and stops

i have hosted the same Service in IIS and its working fine there ,but its not running in Windows Service

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Application Event Log?

Comment: No,i am the administrator of the System and i have configures Service Installer and process Installer correctly ,It starts and stops and gives a Message that Service Stops as no Listener Found

Comment: Do you have other Windows Services that you've written that are working fine?  If this is your first, then I'm thinking something went wrong.  Try creating a trivial windows service without any WCF stuff and see if it works, then work backward to see what's different.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a permission issue. Make sure the user account that the service is running under has an ACL established with http.sys. Run `netsh http show urlacl` from a command line to get a list of existing ACLs. Run `netsh http add urlacl` to add a new one (you must be running as an administrator). The reserved URL should be the same URL you have specified in your WCF service's app.config file.